# JTextField stretches to fill BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout, boxlayout

I have added a `JTextField` to a `JPanel` that is using `BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS`.

I am then adding this panel to a content pane at `BorderLayout.CENTER`.

Right now my text field is stretching the entire width and height of `BorderLayout.CENTER`.

Is there a way to set a width and height of this text field without using a null layout? Or just somehow make it not stretch the entire width and height of `BorderLayout.CENTER`?

I see there is a `JTextField.setMaximumSize(Dimension arg0);` but I'm not sure what a `Dimension` is, or how to utilize it in this context.

Comment: `FlowLayout` will use the preferred size of the `JTextField`.

Comment: *"..but I'm not sure what a `Dimension` is.."*  After reading the [JavaDocs for `Dimension`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html), what is it that you don't understand?

Answer (score 5):

Add a panel to the `CENTER`.  Give the panel a layout that does ***not*** stretch component sizes (e.g `FlowLayout`).  Add the text field to the flow layout.